# Crystal reports formula Syntax

Tags: date, crystal-reports

Need help to create a formula in crystal syntax(Crystal reports) to calculate number of days between two dates from WO_DATE.WO_DATE (WO = work order) where WO_DATE_TYPE.WO_DATE_TYPE_DESC = "START" and WO_DATE_TYPE.WO_DATE_TYPE_DESC = "Due".

Below is my DB Schema

[image: my DB Schema]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Crystal's database expert, add the WO_Date table twice. The 2nd instance would require an Alias (a different name).

Join to require the Work_Order_ID be the same across the two instances.
In the record selection formula, force the first instance to be the START type.
Similarly, force the second instance to be the END type.

Now, simply subtract the date in the first table instance from the date in the second table instance.

Comment: That's a great suggestion but I don't have the authority to modify the DB schema and would increase data redundancy.

Comment: This is not changing the database schema. It is a change to the report design.